# How to calculate the local volatility surface using QuantLib?

Tags: quantlib

I'd like to calculate the local volatility surface for a series of option strikes, similar to the surface described in this paper:

http://www.ederman.com/new/docs/gs-local_volatility_surface.pdf

This is the image I am referring to in the aforementioned paper:

[image]

I know QuantLib has the ability to do this - but what is the correct C# function call(s)?

I'm using the C# build of QuantLib, from:
http://www.resolversystems.com/products/quantlib-binary/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the local-volatility class implemented in `<QuantLib/ql/termstructures/volatility/equityfx/localvolsurface.hpp>`, it's among the several classes that are not exported through SWIG.  You'll have to add it to the SWIG interface files (probably in `volatilities.i`), regenerate the wrappers and recompile them.  If you need instructions on the building process, you can ask on the QuantLib mailing list.

Comment: Oooooh, so that's what I'm missing. Thanks! I'll work with the C++ version directly, once that's working I'll let you know.